# Is there a helper function to generate a link to a member profile for a control panel view?

Tags: ee2, control-panel, add-on-development

Does EE have any built in classes or helper functions to perform common tasks in module code?

In this instance, I want to generate an href to a member profile to use in a control panel view, from a member ID. I have looked in the expression engine core code and not found anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EE has many helper functions - see the [Functions class documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/reference/functions.html) for example. Also, all [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/) helpers and classes can be loaded and used.

If you take a look in the `models` directory, you'll find many helpful methods there as well.

Re: member profile - do you mean on the front-end, or in the control panel? (In either case, I believe the answer is "no" - just built it manually.)

Comment: It's for Control Panel. There are member path global variables for templates, i.e. {path="member/profile"} but I haven't found the equivalent at a class level for module development.

Comment: The equivalent of `{path}` would be `BASE`. e.g., `BASE.AMP.'d=CP'.AMP.'C=myaccount'.AMP.'id='.$member_id`